# When would it be ideal to store a function into a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am currently learning about variables in JavaScript. I understand that functions can be stored into a variable but in what ideal situation to store a function in a variable.

Comment: Whenever you want to be able to reference it later, or more than once

Comment: You store functions in variables when the function can change dynamically. For instance, if you're writing a function that works like `map()`, it takes the function as a parameter.

Comment: One of the key things to learning "modern" languages is that a function is just another datatype, like int or string.  You can have function literals, you can assign them to names, and you can pass functions around just like other objects.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), other than some uses of anonymous [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), are stored as variables in JavaScript. Most of the time when you write functions you will be saving them as variables, otherwise you will only be able to use it once. In JS, functions (and almost everything else) are a type of [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) that have a `name` property and code. When you look at a function declaration like this

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

what you are seeing is a function named `add` being created and stored as a variable. Try it out by writing that function in your browser Console and hitting enter, then just type `add` and it will return to you the function code. Type `add.name` and it returns you the name, the string "add". You can pass the function parameters like `add(2, 3)` and it will return `5`.

That syntax is actually saving the function with the name "add" as the `add` variable. This is much the same as if you had written it like this:

```
let add = function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

You could also write this function expression  without the function name and still save it to the `add` variable. The advantage of writing the name explicitly used to be that that it allowed the function to refer to itself (for [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion)), and also made it easier to identify the function in a debugger. Modern JS interpreters will just infer the name of an anonymous function expression when it is saved to a variable by simply giving it the same name as the variable.

As a traditional function expression, the code just looks like this:

```
let add = function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Under the hood, this is the same as the previous example, and also the same as if you'd written it in with the newer [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax, like this:

```
let add = (x, y) => x + y;
```

One reason you would want to use a truly anonymous function that is *not* saved to a variable is if you are passing a function as a parameter to another function. The built in [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method requires you to pass a function in its first parameter. As an example:

```
setTimeout(function () => {
  console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
}, 1000)
```

These functions are not saved as variables and have no inferred name. Another common pattern you may see with anonymous functions that are not saved to variables is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), also known as a self-executing anonymous function.

Just so you're aware, the primary difference with most use cases between writing a function as a declaration and as an expression is that function declarations, like other variables and Classes, are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). This means that no matter what order in the code you place a function declaration, it will automatically be interpreted as if it had been placed at the top of its [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). This means that it is possible to use a function written as a function declaration before it is actually declared. This is not possible with function expressions, which cannot be used before they appear in the code. Best practice is to avoid needing hoisting at all and to simply place functions, classes, and other variables in their logical order. Like many things in JS, hoisting has unintuitive results and not understanding how it works while having unorderly code can lead to unpredictable behavior and errors.

Comment: One thing to note about this is that `function` declarations are hoisted, whereas the variable declaration is hoisted but the assignment is not. This means that `function add` can be referenced before its declaration, but `let add = function` cannot.

Comment: Thanks. This is why I wrote "much the same" and linked to the documentation on MDN. Was going to go back through with an edit and add the differences between the two.